# Common emitter configuration opposite

Tags: common-emitter

What is the simplest circuit of common emitter configuration inverse that is switching to open on high base current and to close/shorted on no/low base current?

Comment: `close/shorted on no/low base current` ... do you really mean `low current`? ... or are you assuming that low base voltage equates to low current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest it so just put another common emitter stage in front of it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOSYgr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>